# C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type

Tags: c++

I am trying to get stockname to my derived class using a return function, but it shows a error 'argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type'.
   strcpy(name,s.name()); //Problem
I tried to make it a constant char but that made a couple of errors.
I am making a project on stock market, text me your ideas.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class stock
{
    char stockname[20];
    float istockprice;
    float fstockprice;
    int demand;
public:
    void senter();
    void sdisplay();
    int demands()
    {
        return demand;
    }
    char name()
    {
        return s.stockname[20];
    }
};
class market : public stock 
{
    char stocksell[20];
    char stockbuy[20];
    float sellprice;
    float rate;
public:
    void marketdata();
    void rate();
    void search();
};
class transaction
{
public: 
    void credit();
    void debit();
    void transfer();
};
market m;
transaction t;
stock s;
void market::rate()
{
    m.rate = demands();
    m.rate += 1;
}
void market::search()
{
    char name[30];
    strcpy(name,s.name()); //Problem
    ifstream search("Marketdata.txt");
    if (!search)
    {
        cout << "Marketdata.txt file error";
        return;
    }
    //while (search.read((char*)& m, sizeof(m)))
    //{
    //  if (strcmp(m.stocksell,name)==0)
        //{

        //}

//    }
}
```

Comment: forget char[] and use std::string.

Comment: You are not returning a string, but 1 chararcter. And this character is out of bounds. strcpy, can only copy from strings, not from a single char.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused about C style strings (and arrays). In C++ you should really use C++ style strings, but you've started this code with C strings so we'll carry on with that for now.

In C a string is an array of characters, to manipulate the string you need a **pointer** to the first element of the array. So this code is wrong

```
char name()
{
    return s.stockname[20];
}
```

Firstly there's a total spurious `s` in there, I don't know what you think that does (and I'm surprised it compiles). But the main point is that because this is a C style string, the function should return a pointer.

```
char* name() // returns a pointer
{
    return stockname;
}
```

So `stockname` is an array containing a C style string, and `name` is a method which returns a pointer to the first element of the array.

Weird as it is, that how you do strings in C. C++ strings are so much easier, in many different ways. If you really want to learn C++, you should leave all the legacy C stuff behind.